# when should i initialize javascript properties?

Tags: javascript, properties, convention

I am new to javascript and I've been wondering about something. Is there an accepted way I should be listing my object properties?

To be specific, I have been writing code where an object is created without any initial properties and adding them on as the code runs.

Example:

```
Game = {};
Game.x = 0;
...Code code code
Game.thing = function ()  {
    Game.variable = 30;
}
```

As you can see, my Game object is just slowly gathering properties as my code runs on. Is this acceptable? Or should I be listing out all the properties I will be using at the beginning in my Game object initialization? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
var Game = { // DON'T FORGET var !!!!!
  x: 0,
  something: some_value,
  thing: function() {
    this.variable = 30;
  }
};
```

What you're doing in your code is not really wrong (except don't forget `var`!!).  It's a matter of style and intent.  The above code (well the part in the curly braces) is called an "object literal", and it's a way of creating an object as a JavaScript value on the fly. It's very useful, but it's not necessarily *better* than other ways of building an object.

*edit*

Note that according to [this article](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Optimization-killers#5-for-in) when an object (in V8 at least, though I suspect other runtimes are likely to have similar behavior) starts looking like it's being used like a map, then it internally is optimized for that purpose. After that point, `for ... in` loops over the object will no longer be candidates for optimization. You can (I think) still use `Object.keys()` to do such iterations, and overall it's probably a net benefit, but it might be the case that objects that experience a lot of property creation fall into that situation.

Comment: You should explain why this is better.

Comment: @RobertHarvey well I've been thinking about what to say; it's not necessarily *better*; it's just different.

Comment: @Pointy I understand, but I was wondering if I should list out all my properties before I do anything with them, or is it okay to add properties to my object real-time? Like say, 300 lines down I add a new property to the object that isn't listed at the beginning. Is that okay?

Comment: @jahmezz funny you should ask this - I was just reading an article on this the other day. I'll extend the answer a little.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on your application. If you have all of the data you want to put in your object when you create it, use an object literal:

```
var Game = {
    x: 0,
    thing = function ()  {
        this.variable = 30;
    }
}
```

However, there may be instances where you want to add to your newly created object as you go. This is common when namespacing (which it seems like you're trying to do).

I would start with something like this:

```
var Game = Game || {};
```

That way, you make sure you aren't colliding with another object. Then go from there, by adding your properties and methods. A common approach is to create a closure and assign new methods from within that closure.

```
(function() {
    var foo = function () {
        ... stuff ...
    }
    Game.foo = foo;
})();
```

That way, you don't run the risk of accidentally creating any global variables. :)

Comment: Yes, I am attempting to namespace. Thanks for the input!

Comment: To clarify, the extra () create a closure? And it looks like it keeps all global definitions from going beyond the braces, am I right? @SeeMeCode

Comment: Basically that just allows you to create a [self invoking function](http://sarfraznawaz.wordpress.com/2012/01/26/javascript-self-invoking-functions/), which you would want since you're creating an anonymous function to act as a closure. It's the actual function that creates a closure – [all functions in JS are automatic closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures).